# How to import AVCHD to macOS while also deinterlacing during import?

Tags: avchd

When I import AVCHD from my Sony camera into macOS via different apps (such as AVCHD to Mov from the App Store), I always end up with interlaced video and then have to pass it through additional filters to deinterlace it.

How can I import the video while simultaneously deinterlacing it?  I have heard that it can be done, but I've not found the method to accomplish this.

Comment: I haven’t done research on this, but I’m guessing it’s possible with a tool such as ffmpeg, but I doubt it’s possible with the built-in MacOS import tools (based on experience, I have found there are very few available options during import on MacOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handbrake is really good for deinterlacing video. Under Filters choose Yadif for best result or Decomb for automatic recognition of interlaced frames.